# ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher (error handling)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

While updating a service reference of my WCF client (simply by clicking *Update Service Reference* in Visual Studio 2008), following error occurs:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException:
>   The message with Action
>   'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/transfer/Get'
>   cannot be processed at the receiver,
>   due to a ContractFilter mismatch at
>   the EndpointDispatcher. This may be
>   because of either a contract mismatch
>   (mismatched Actions between sender and
>   receiver) or a binding/security
>   mismatch between the sender and the
>   receiver.  Check that sender and
>   receiver have the same contract and
>   the same binding (including security
>   requirements, e.g. Message, Transport,
>   None).     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorBehavior.ThrowAndCatch(Exception
>   e, Message message)

Background:

I've created `ErrorServiceBehaviour` class. Because such a behavior is created for error handling, `IErrorHandler` implementation must be applied to each `ChannelDispatcher`.

```
public class ErrorServiceBehaviour : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
{
   ...
   public Type FaultType
   {
      get { return _faultType; }
      set { _faultType = value; }
   }

   public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
   {
       foreach (ChannelDispatcher dispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
       {
           dispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(new ErrorHandler(_faultType));
       }
   }
}

public class ErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
{
     public ErrorHandler(Type faultType)
     {
        _faultType = faultType;         
     }
     ...
}
```

Later, I've used that behaviour by applying `ErrorServiceBehavior` attribute to my service class:

```
[ErrorServiceBehavior(FaultType = typeof(MyServiceFault))] 
public class MyService : IMyService
{
   ...
}
```

The thing is, when I comment out the `foreach` loop inside `ApplyDispatchBehavior` method, I get **no** error at all, but that is not the way out (because I want my errors to be handled).

Below there is my service config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="MyService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IMyService" bindingConfiguration="NoSecurityBinding"/>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="DefaultBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="NoSecurityBinding" >
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
                    <message establishSecurityContext="false"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="DefaultBinding" />
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Can someone help me?

**UPDATE**

The code shown earlier:

```
foreach (ChannelDispatcher dispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
{
    dispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(new ErrorHandler(_faultType));
}
```

adds custom error handling for all endpoints - including the metadata one. But actually this is **not** the source of the problem - even when I disable adding error handling for metadata endpoint, the issue still occurs.

The other notice is, when I change the `bindingConfiguration` of the first endpoint to `DefaultBinding`, I have **no** error at all:

```
<services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="MyService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IMyService" bindingConfiguration="DefaultBinding"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
</services>
```

Such an option in also not what I want - I still need problematic `NoSecurityBinding` to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the [IExtensibleDataObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iextensibledataobject.aspx), it is used to handle different versions of a web service still being able to communicate with each other. This way the contracts don't need to match exactly. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, I notice your try to bind a *mexHttpBinding* to an endpoint although it was never defined inside your "Bindings" tag. This should rise an exception, and I would expect such an exception to look like the one that's bothering you.

```
 <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

...

<bindings>
    <mexHttpBinding>
        THIS TAG WAS MISSING (add security features as needed)
    </mexHttpBinding>

    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NoSecurityBinding" >
            <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="DefaultBinding" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Also, since you apparently dont need any security feature, you might want to favor basicHttpBinding. As this [very thorough answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650785/basichttpbinding-vs-wshttpbinding-vs-webhttpbinding?answertab=votes#2650899) states, wsHttpBinding really is useful when you *want* security features.

Your configuration would end up being almost the same, changing "ws" for "basic".

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="MyService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IMyService" bindingConfiguration="NoSecurityBinding"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DefaultBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NoSecurityBinding" >
            <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="DefaultBinding" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I'm not going to verify it though since the question was asked around 5 years ago. Nevertheless I appreciate it.

Comment: Wow, it poped in the "not answered" questions, I didnt expect the system to push such old topics. Anyway, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `App.Config` and verify that it is pointing to your deployed Windows service host or set it to point to `localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

On what you say it seems that your new **WCF** service do require security and in your **NoSecurityBinding** you turn it off.
One way to check that is to get **WSDL** file locally an see if it has: **http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd** or **http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy** or something like that in imports. I'm pretty  sure that your updated WCF service has security enabled

---

**Update 1**

To get a better vision of your problem you could use WCF Tracing. Here you could see how to turn it on and how to read that traces: ["How to turn on WCF tracing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271517/how-to-turn-on-wcf-tracing?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are turning the security completely off. Try this:

```
<bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="NoSecurityBinding" >
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
                    <message clientCredentialType="None"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="DefaultBinding" />
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Existing web.config setting can create a problem as they are for previous version.
Better to remove existing reference from your WCF client application and Add the reference again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" name="Service">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: While your answer may solve the question, it is always better if you can provide a description of what the issue was and how your answer solves it. This is a suggestion for further improving this and future answers.

Comment: Will Keep it in my mind...!! Thanks for your Advices