# How to turn on WCF tracing?

Tags: wcf

**Update:**

I have been trying to turn on [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) tracing, but still no success... Below is my lastest update.

Do I need a permission to write to the below location?

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="sdt"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData= "@\\myservername\folder1\traces.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

I am using .NET Framework 3.5.

What is the step-by-step instruction to turn on the WCF tracking for debugging purposes?

Answer (score 235, accepted):

The following configuration taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) can be applied to enable tracing on your [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) service.

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true" >
        <listeners>
             <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
            <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="myUserTraceSource"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
            <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add name="xml"
             type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
             initializeData="Error.svclog" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

To view the log file, you can use "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\SvcTraceViewer.exe".

If "SvcTraceViewer.exe" is not on your system, you can download it from the "Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4" package here:

[Windows SDK Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279)

You don't have to install the entire thing, just the ".NET Development / Tools" part.

When/if it bombs out during installation with a non-sensical error, [Petopas' answer to *Windows 7 SDK Installation Failure*](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssdk/thread/8f3350f9-0b47-40ae-b070-f2ccbf041875/) solved my issue.

Comment: where do i see the file is genereated `Error.svclog` ?

Comment: i have implemented in the web.config on my dev box but i dont see that it generate any `svclog` file is there any other setting needs to be taken care?

Comment: The file will be generated in the same directory as your assembly. Most likely your bin directory. You may need recycle the worker process if you services are hosted in IIS.

Comment: my wcf servcies is hosted on IIS on the dev box and i am using those servcies from my local machine, so i do have access to the folder/files are in dev box and i looked into bin folder and other foloers but could not find the log file...

Comment: Make sure that your Application Pool - Identity has permission to write to that folder. I usually have a dedicated account assigned to my application pool, this way i can grant read\write access to that specific user

Comment: Will this `Tracing` will work in `Release Mode`. ? If yes.. how can we disable it ?

Comment: In the development environment, the Error file (initializeData="Error.svclog") is stored inside the solution project. Changing it to other locations did not work.

Comment: I recomand you to use the powerfull "Microsoft Service Configuration Editor" (embeded with visual studio in my case). You cannot do everything, but it helps a lot in understanding WCF configuration, including log configuration

Comment: I was able to get it to log to a folder by using this: initializeData="C:\wcflogs\wcf_svclog.svclog" />

Comment: @RohanWest - Actually - in my case the file was generated in the ROOT folder of my application (hosted on IIS), not the bin folder. It seems that it is relative to the web.config path, not the assembly path.

Comment: What is myUserTraceSource?

Comment: see how to configure it using a UI: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34283667/187650 :-)

Comment: When i add the <system.diagnostics> tag under <configuration> i get an error saying The content type text/html of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml;

Comment: @user1152145, the solution to that problem is to paste it at the end of the file, just above </configuration>.

Answer (score 37):

In your web.config (on the server) add

```
<system.diagnostics>
 <sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
   <listeners>
    <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\logs\Traces.svclog"/>
   </listeners>
  </source>
 </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: i have added like this since i dont have access to the dev except the folder `initializeData="\\servername\drive$\Project\WCFTraces.svclog"/>` and i dont see that file is generated after i try to access the services.

Comment: By default it is buffered (may be able to change this).  You can force it to flush by recycling the app pool.  Also make sure the app pool identity can write to the location.

Answer (score 21):

Go to your Microsoft SDKs directory. A path like this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools
```

Open the WCF Configuration Editor (Microsoft Service Configuration Editor) from that directory:

```
SvcConfigEditor.exe
```

*(another option to open this tool is by navigating in Visual Studio 2017 to  "Tools" > "WCF Service Configuration Editor")*

[image: wcf configuration editor]

Open your .config file or create a new one using the editor and navigate to Diagnostics.

There you can click the "Enable MessageLogging".

[image: enable messagelogging]

More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732009(v=vs.110).aspx

With the trace viewer from the same directory you can open the trace log files:

```
SvcTraceViewer.exe
```

You can also enable tracing using WMI. More info:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks you so much for introducing me to this GUI utility. it will make editing the config files a lot easier!

Comment: Awesome.it helps me a lot to understand the Tracelog .

Answer (score 1):

Instead of you manual adding the tracing enabling bit into web.config you can also try using the WCF configuration editor which comes with VS SDK to enable tracing

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16715631/2218571