# WCF service stability

Tags: wcf, amazon-ec2

I have a WCF service, self hosted by a simple console app, and a few clients sending requests on a regular basis. 1 client is a web site (using net pipe), 1 client is a scheduler (using net pipe with 1min interval) and 1 last client is another scheduler but this one running from a remote machine (through basic http binding port 80 with also 1min interval)

All seems well so far. I hosted everything on an Amazon VM, and for some reason, when I return in the morning, none of the clients can connected anymore, either the host isn't reachable or the requests time out.

I have no idea where to start looking, any suggestion is appreciaetd!

Thanks all!

Seb :)

Comment: enable WCF tracing

" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271517/how-to-turn-on-wcf-tracing"

Comment: Thanks I'll start with that :)