# Debugging Tool for Web Service

Tags: android, mysql, wcf, ksoap2, genymotion

I'm writing an Android app with process:

Android app (ksoap2, GenyMotion virtual device) <-> WCF service (localhost) <-> MySQL (localhost)

I could add SOAP request, use service to operate with database and get SOAP response successfully at the beginning with few features. But since my app need more features, I have to declare more variables, more classes, more objects, more Activities..., the app's logic and handling are more complex and I encounter some bugs in WCF code to operate with database but I can't reach any error log. Is there any debugging tool that I could keep track of all the data in overall process? Such as:

values of variables in Android app <-> add to SOAP request or get from SOAP response <-> values of properties in SOAP request or SOAP response (WSDL) <-> values of variables in WCF service <-> log errors when select, insert, update, delete... to database

Comment: Assuming you have Android Studio, run the apk in debug mode, use try /catch to catch exceptions and view system log, work with breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the 'Apache TCPMon' Utility, using this you can see the Request, Response headers including the SOAP messages from and to WCF.

You can download it here.. it is free.

http://archive.apache.org/dist/ws/tcpmon/

for the 'values of variables in WCF service', you can check the documentation 
how to enable DEBUG/LOG Messages

see here for 'How to debug WCF Service':

[How to debug a WCF service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545702/how-to-debug-a-wcf-service)