# Missing XmlWriterTraceListener on Windows 8

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, windows-8

In testing our app on a windows 8 x64 server, we ran into an issue that
when adding an XmlWriterTraceListner to the app config file, the service is throwing a class not found exception.

> Service cannot be started.
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Couldn't find type
>   for class System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.

It's my understanding that Windows 8 should already have .net 4.0 installed?  Why is it missing this class?  Any official workaround for this problem?

Comment: It seems that you need to enable tracing abilities explicitly. Here are the steps to follow : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4271597/795876

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to turn on WCF Tracing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271517/how-to-turn-on-wcf-tracing)

Comment: resolved the issue by removing the explicit assembly version info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved the issue by removing the explicit assembly version info