# Logging the request received by a WCF service

Tags: wcf, logging, soap

is there a way to log the incoming request to a WCF service?

I have a simple WCF service hosted as Windows Service. The WCF service writes logs on a daily basis.
Some times there a bad-requests coming in and I would want to log then too.

Is there a way to log the SOAP request that comes in?
That way it would help to show the client what mistakes they are making.

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add to @RoelF 's response since he mentioned below

> Although I'm not sure how to exactly log the content of the SOAP
>   messages, this method can provide you with a lot of extra info,
>   expecially if you implement a timed logging.

So here is the line you'd use to get the SOAP request from those AfterCall BeforeCall methods.

```
Message message = OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage;
```

Then you could log message.ToString() . This should log the SOAP request that you are after.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to implement an `IServiceBehavior` and an `IParameterInspector` class, which will handle the logging.

**IServiceBehavior**
The `ApplyDispatchBehavior` is the most important method to implement:

```
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        foreach (ChannelDispatcher dispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            foreach (var endpoint in dispatcher.Endpoints)
            {
                foreach (var dispatchOperation in endpoint.DispatchRuntime.Operations)
                {
                    dispatchOperation.ParameterInspectors.Add(new LoggingParameterInspector(/*reference to your logger*/));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You have to apply this `ServiceBehavior`to your service, either by making it an `Attribute` on your service implementation class, or by adding it to the definition at startup time.

**IParameterInspector**
this interface has two methods: `BeforeCall` and `AfterCall`. In the implementation of these methods you can access the operation name and the inputs given to the method. This allows you to create a clean and simple trace of all calls to the service.

Although I'm not sure how to exactly log the content of the SOAP messages, this method can provide you with a lot of extra info, expecially if you implement a timed logging.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure tracing and level of tracing in the configuration file of your service. To view the log files, Microsoft has supplied a special trace log viewer. Normally you can just double click the trace files to open them in this viewer.

This has been answered many times on SO, example [How to turn on WCF tracing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271517/how-to-turn-on-wcf-tracing)

Documentation on MSDN
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Sample configuration

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true" >
        <listeners>
             <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
            <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="myUserTraceSource"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
            <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add name="xml"
             type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
             initializeData="Error.svclog" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```