# WCF endpoint deployment error

Tags: wcf, endpoint

I created 2 WCF endpoints, the service endpoint resides on a desktop app(with IP address 10.8.20.175); the client endpoint resides on a web-hosted application.

this is service endpoint config

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="NotificationServiceBehavior"
    name="NotificationService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="INotificationService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:3337/NotificationService" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

and this is client endpoint config

```
<system.serviceModel>
<client>
  <endpoint address="net.tcp://10.8.20.175:3337/NotificationService"
    binding="netTcpBinding" contract="INotificationService"
    name="NetTcpBinding_INotificationService" />
</client>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000" name="NetTcpBinding_INotificationService"/>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

notice that in the endpoint address, I put the actual IP address of service endpoint. when I tested the communication between service endpoint and client endpoint on localhost, that address was localhost:3337 and the communication was good. now when I deploy the endpoint I got the following errors:

The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, 
or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:10:00'.

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)

The log says that the connection was forcibly closed by the remote host, that means the client endpoint actually sent request and it reached the service endpoint? I am confused at this point. I am not sure if the client endpoint can reach the service endpoint.

btw, from the client endpoint machine, I can ping the machine of service endpoint and also can do telnet on the port 3337 to the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this indicates that your service has been reached by the client and activated. However something happened during the call that killed the reply from the service.

Best way to check would be to turn on [WCF tracing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271517/how-to-turn-on-wcf-tracing) for your service. This should help give you a better insight into what's happening server side.

Comment: I have turned on WCF tracing on both service side and client side. However, I only got the log file on client side. The reason I think is because the client side is on a web-host app, but the service side is on desktop app. does anyone know how to turn on WCF tracing on desktop app? thanks!

Comment: The chosen answer for the link in my answer should have all the configuration needed for you're app.config. The configuration should be the same regardless of if you are running a web or desktop application. Are you executing the desktop app as a user that doesn't have access to where you are trying to write the file? Edit: You could also give a tool like Wireshark or Netmon a go on your server to confirm there is chatter between your apps.