# Debugging the windows network stack for WCF service

Tags: wcf, trace

I'm about to go and visit a client where we've been having some odd connectivity issues talking to a WCF based service. The WCF service is being hosted by a windows service rather than IIS.

On the client side I'm happy to use fiddler and I'm also using WCF tracing at the server end to generate a service trace file. On the wire I can use WireShark to see what's going on, my worry is that there is a little black hole between the windows network stack and the web service at the server end.

Does anyone know of a network shim or something that can grab the data at the server end between windows and the WCF service? (or can I configure fiddler to do this?)

Comment: Have you looked at [How to turn on WCF Tracing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271517/how-to-turn-on-wcf-tracing) and [Configuring Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)?

Comment: Yep, my question is if there is a mechanism for logging the bit between the network and the WCF service. It's the one bit of the system I can't really get into. I should be able to watch packets over the wire but I can't tell if another process is grabbing the data before my WCF service. Probably isn't a real world issue but given what my co-worker told me after his last visit I'm just trying to cover the various potential failure points. I *Suspect* I'm actually going to find some misconfiguration somewhere but since I have to go on site I'm trying to prepare for everything.

Comment: Tracing _does_ show methods called on and data sent with various System.Net components, which WCF heavily relies on. Just be sure to include System.Net as trace source. See also [How to: Configure Network Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824.aspx).