# Debugging ASMX is easy, debugging WCF isn't

Tags: c#, ajax, wcf, web-services, asmx

I've always used ASMX Web Services for when I need to do AJAX, but I'm just starting to use WCF Web Services because, well, it's newer and better isn't it? Not exactly sure why I want to use WCF, probably the same reason I upgraded from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2012.

I have the exact same method in `WS.asmx` as I do in `WS.svc`, but when I set a break point on both, I'm only able to step through the ASMX method. Why?

I don't think the code is relevant but I'll paste anyway..

ASMX:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string FetchData(string jsonAOData)
{
    // some code here throws an exception
    return "";
}
```

WCF:

```
[OperationContract]
public string FetchData(string jsonAOData)
{
    // some code here throws an exception
    return "";
}
```

Anyone know why I can't step through the WCF method?

Comment: If you are looking for something newer and better, check out servicestack.net - debugging it is a breeze, amongst many other benefits.

Comment: I debugged dozens of wcfs and they always debug like a breeze.

Comment: I usually host my web apps in IIS, and debug them **clicking on Debug > Attach to Process > select "w3wp.exe" process > click Attach**

Comment: "I can't step through it"? Are you sure the method is even being _called_?

Comment: hi, there is tracing tool as part of .NET, which will help you enable tracing and view the trace check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679104/trace-wcf-call-from-client/16715631#16715631