# Cannot add record to database when using WCF service

Tags: wcf, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am able to add a record to my database when using WCF basicHttpBinding and running the client & service locally. The DB is my production DB.

When running the client & service directly from the shared hosting site, the record can't be added with no error being recorded.

Note that this situation only happens while adding only certain records in a specific scenario and all others go through. However, I debugged it locally and everything is fine. I have a feeling it may be a setting I need to put on my service behaivors. Below is the config section for my behaivors.

Does anyone have an idea what I may need to add or if they have encountered this themselves and found another solution?

```
<serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!--To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment-->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
          <!--To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information-->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
```

Comment: There should have been some fault by the service if there was any issue with WCF service while adding records. It would be helpful if you can elaborate a little bit on certain records in a specific scenario.

Comment: Can you try and enable tracing on the service and check the trace files to know more about the issue.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679104/trace-wcf-call-from-client/16715631#16715631