# How to turn on WCF tracing at the client side?

Tags: c#, wcf, trace

I want to use the WCF tracing feature. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271517/how-to-turn-on-wcf-tracing) I found a help to turn on the WCF tracing at the service side.

Now I want to enable the WCF tracing feature at the client side for a WCF service that I can consume only.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/908f7f5a-a166-42c6-b323-aebd06576e0a/how-to-log-or-trace-message-at-wcf-client-side

Comment: @rags Thanks it works for me. May you submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this link for enabling the trace on client side:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/908f7f5a-a166-42c6-b323-aebd06576e0a/how-to-log-or-trace-message-at-wcf-client-side

Answer (score 4):

It's the same as the server side : add this section in your client's config file (web or app) :

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.di​agnostics​>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData= "C:\LogFolder\LogFile.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```