# WCF Service Authentication. Error is never returned when credentials is wrong

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

I am writing a quite simple WCF-service with username/password authentication. My code for the username/password validator looks like this:

```
public class InvoiceServiceUserValidation : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            throw new SecurityTokenException("Username and password required");
        }

        if (InvoiceServiceHelper.AuthenticateUser(userName, password)) return;

        throw new FaultException("Could not authenticate - Unknown reason");

    }
}
```

If I supply the correct username and password, everything is fine, and the operations continue. When I supply the wrong password, hovever, the exception is never returned, so my client just stays there waiting before it times out.

I have debugged so I know the line with "throw new FaultException" is actually reached when it is wrong, but still no answer to the client.

Help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you need to turn logging on for wcf. Once stuff passes the edges of your code you cant debug directly, logging however will get you a lot further into the problem. Especially when you start to use interception.

[How to turn on WCF tracing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271517/how-to-turn-on-wcf-tracing)

when you have this you can look at the logs and figure out exactly what is happening.
If you still cant figure it out id suggest asking a new question or else this will get put on hold.

what is your front end. Is it silverlight?

You say it is timing out - increase the time out to something silly like 10 mins. Does it timeout straight away.

is the connection being aborted, is fault code 500?
fire up fiddler

Comment: In the trace it seems to me that the exception is thrown, but still the client does not receive it. There is a slight opportunity that I do not know how to read the trace file, however

Comment: yeah they are hard. you can get traces on both sides of the boundary.

Comment: How do I get traces on the client side? The same config lines in the app.config?

Comment: basically yes. I haven't had to play with wcf for over a year so don't have any sample files to hand. I'd just have to google it. Search on here i bet there are about 50 questions asking the exact same thing. eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591169/how-to-turn-on-wcf-tracing-at-the-client-side

Comment: Nothing in the traces to help me, the only thing I can see is that the error is not caught on the client side...

Comment: oh are you throwing the right exception? have you tried just throwing a normal exception or a securitytokenexception?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why, but when I switched to wsHttpBinding (From wsDualHttpBinding) this started working. It is not really a solution as much as a workaround, but that solved it for me.

If anyone else is struggling with the same, this may be the case.