# WCF RESTful Service not work after server restarted

Tags: wcf, iis-6

Envirment:
Windows Server 2003 + IIS 6
.Net Framework 4.0

I have a well-worked WCF RESTful service hosted in IIS6, Windows Server 2003.

Each time Server restarted, this service will down and response status code is 404.
Then restart IIS, problem fixed.
Other non-WCF-RESTful services on the same IIS has no this problem.

My Server is scheduled to restart once everyday, so I have to restart IIS after each server started.

I have no idea why this happened an what cause WCF RESTful returned 404.
Is there anyone help to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to figure out what happens on service side. Add an error handler to you service and log every exception (you can use log4net for that).

Here is an example:

[Error handling](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/07/wcf-extensibility-ierrorhandler.aspx)

Or to simplify the task you can just torn on Tracing:

[WCF tracing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271517/how-to-turn-on-wcf-tracing)