# WCF client the underlying connection was closed

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, .net-4.8

Something unexpected appeared on two machines (out of 5) with our software running on it. It uses a WCF client to exchange SOAP messages and everything was working fine until 5th september 2023 where the exception below is constantly thrown at the first request our software makes.

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
<EventID>131075</EventID>
<Type>3</Type>
<SubType Name="Error">0</SubType>
<Level>2</Level>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-09-05T12:31:37.7290515Z" />
<Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
<Correlation ActivityID="{2d89b0b7-60bc-425c-9b5f-4a56c81f9965}" />
<Execution ProcessName="Panipro.PosEcosystem.TerminalApplication.UI" ProcessID="7112" ThreadID="9" />
<Channel />
<Computer>DESKTOP-ARKAQ4J</Computer>
</System>
<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>Levée d'une exception.</Description>
<AppDomain>Panipro.PosEcosystem.TerminalApplication.UI.exe</AppDomain>
<Exception>
<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>La connexion sous-jacente a été fermée : La connexion a été interrompue de manière inattendue.</Message>
<StackTrace>
à System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
à System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
à System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
à System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
à System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
à System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
à System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
à System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&amp; msgData, Int32 type)
à BrueBoxService.BrueBoxPortType.OpenOperation(OpenOperationRequest request)
à BrueBoxService.BrueBoxPortTypeClient.BrueBoxService.BrueBoxPortType.OpenOperation(OpenOperationRequest request)
à Panipro.PosEcosystem.TerminalApplication.Infrastructure.Peripherals.CashRecyclers.FCC.Fcc.Open(OpenRequest request)
à Panipro.PosEcosystem.TerminalApplication.Infrastructure.Peripherals.CashRecyclers.Requests.Open.DoInternal(Fcc client, String id, String SequenceNumber, String sessionId)
à Panipro.PosEcosystem.TerminalApplication.Infrastructure.Peripherals.CashRecyclers.Requests.Request`1.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass0_0.&lt;Do&gt;b__1()
à System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
à System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
à System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(Object obj)
à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
à System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task&amp; currentTaskSlot)
à System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean bPreventDoubleExecution)
à System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
à System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
à System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: La connexion sous-jacente a été fermée : La connexion a été interrompue de manière inattendue. ---&gt; System.Net.WebException: La connexion sous-jacente a été fermée : La connexion a été interrompue de manière inattendue.
   à System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   à System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   --- Fin de la trace de la pile d'exception interne ---</ExceptionString>
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.Net.WebException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>La connexion sous-jacente a été fermée : La connexion a été interrompue de manière inattendue.</Message>
<StackTrace>
à System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
à System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.Net.WebException: La connexion sous-jacente a été fermée : La connexion a été interrompue de manière inattendue.
   à System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   à System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)</ExceptionString>
</InnerException>
</Exception>
</TraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

This was already collected by enabling WCF logs but the exception is still meaningless on the failure's reason.

The only change I can see between 4th and 5th september is a "Security Intelligence Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Version 1.397.412.0)".

I also mention that I don't have access to the "server" hosting the SOAP endpoints. The client was generated based on a WSDL file provided to me by the corporation hosting the service. No change was made on the server during this period. I have tried to access with both HTTP and HTTPS to make sure it was not encryption-related but the error stays the same.

The faulting machines run with the following configuration:

- Windows 10 Entreprise LTSC 10.0.17763
- .NET Framework 4.8.03761
- Windows Defender disabled (through GPEdit)
- No other anti-virus

Any idea what could be the reason of this exception ?

Comment: The Logs you post do not reflect specific error messages. Have you tried other tools like `WcfTestClient.exe` , `SvcConfigEditor.exe`,or `SvcTraceViewer.exe`.

Comment: @Jiayao Unfortunately it already is what I get in the svclog file (shown in `SvcTraceViewer.exe`).

Comment: Did you get any more detailed logs? The logs you listed are not the problem. You can check the points listed in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121360/display-wcf-data-the-underlying-connection-was-closed) to find the problem.

Comment: @Jiayao The problem was server-side (see my own answer).

Answer (score 0):

It appeared that the problem lied on the server-side which crashed after receiving a request and was unable to correctly respond, hence the WCF message "the underlying connection was closed unexpectedly".