# Intercepting WCF calls in thick clients that uses nettcpbinding? is it possible and how?

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding, intercept

Considering the following scenario,

I have a thick client that communicate with server through (Windows communication foundation) WCF using nettcpbinding.

Is there any way to intercept the traffic and/or alter it.

Comment: You need to define "traffic". Do you mean TCP packets or the soap messages sent using the TCP transport?

Comment: @SixtoSaez the soap messages in first place, or TCP packets if i can modify the parameters in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to intercept the WCF soap messages for **debugging** on either the client or service is to [turn on the built-in WCF tracing feature.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271517/how-to-turn-on-wcf-tracing) You can configure it to only log soap messages by only adding the `<source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">` element.

If you want programmatic access to the soap message then you can implement the `IClientMessageInspector` behavior in your client application. This [blog post on message inspectors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/04/19/wcf-extensibility-message-inspectors.aspx) describes how you would implement and configure the `IClientMessageInspector`.

I don't have an experience doing low-level inspection of TCP packets but you can look at the free [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/about.html) tool to work with TCP packets.

Comment: thanks a lot for your contribution, but am searching for technique to be used within already developed application with no access to its source code.

Comment: Actually, that's not a problem as long as the client is using the client-side WCF classes to invoke a service. Adding a message inspector is done through configuration (as shown in the linked blog post). You just need to create a standalone DLL to contain the `IClientMessageInspector` implementation and register that behavior through the application .config file.

Comment: I meant by intercepting is to have the ability to change the SOAP message after doing the action on the application, and before the soap message is sent to the server.

something like fiddler and burpproxy  which intercepts HTTP requests, but i need that for nettcpbinding.

Comment: You need to add code to the `BeforeSendRequest` method of the `IClientMessageInspector` implementation to manipulate the soap XML. This [blog post shows how to modify the contents of a text node.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stcheng/archive/2009/02/21/wcf-how-to-inspect-and-modify-wcf-message-via-custom-messageinspector.aspx)