# Async method does not execute when passing interface as parameter

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, visual-studio, asynchronous

having a weird issue... I'm passing an interface as a parameter to an asynchronous method and it never executes (breakpoint, debug.break, etc never hit).  As follows:

```
ITestClass test = new TestClass();
IAsyncResult asyncResult = serviceProxy.beginWork(test);
```

The Work() method never, well, works!  No breakpoint is hit inside the Work() method and no error is ever thrown.  I can get Work() to work if I do as follows

```
IAsyncResult asyncResult = serviceProxy.beginWork(new QueueServiceClient());
```

-or-

```
IAsyncResult asyncResult = serviceProxy.beginWork(null);
```

Any ideas or rules that I don't know about passing an interface into an asynchronous method in C#?

Comment: Can you show `beginWork` implementation?

Comment: Make sure that your interface `ITestClass` has `KnownType` attribute for the derived types. WCF needs this to function.

Comment: Turn on [WCF trace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271517/how-to-turn-on-wcf-tracing) and have a look at the log. That way you can at least get more information of what went wrong.