# Logging raw HTTP (Xml?) Request/Response for MSCRM 2011 calls via SDK

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

What would be the simplest way to achieve this? I am using the objects and functions in the Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.* namespaces to talk to the CRM instance. As an example, I can log requests/responses when using ASMX by using SoapExtension. What is the equivalent for the MSCRM SDK? I've read that it uses WCF under the hood but I'm not sure if it's SOAP or REST or anything or how much it matters. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming this is a client application connecting to CRM and not code running in a plugin/workflow?

Comment: @Nicknow Yes that's correct.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4271597/999042 (How to enable WCF tracing)

Answer (score 0):

I think simplest way will be use logging proxy. [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) is a great choice for that.

Definitely you will face some challenges, like make `Fiddler` to capture all traffic, even if it is not set up as proxy explicitly, decrypting `https` calls, or unwrapping `SOAP` envelopes, but overall it's issues easy to overcome.