# Publish/subscribe WCF over wifi using websocket

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, azure, websocket

I've got a little bit tricky problem. It's all about my new WPF app. I'm using publish/subscribe wcf (hosted on Azure VM) and websocket (netHttpBinding) connection.

Everything works perfect while I'm using cable (LAN) connection. But when I'm using Wifi connection I don't get any response from wcf.

Little example here:

*both of (app/web).config files contains:*

```
<netHttpBinding>
    <binding name="NetHttpBinding_IPublishSubscribeAlpha" closeTimeout="01:00:00" openTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
        <webSocketSettings transportUsage="Always" />
    </binding>
</netHttpBinding>
```

*in app code to connect:*

```
_connection = new Connection();
_connection.Callback.OnIdReceived += callback_OnIdReceived;
...
_connection.Client.RegisterClient("User" + Guid.NewGuid());
```

*wcf code:*

```
var callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IPublishSubscribeCallback>();
await callback.SendClientId(client.Id);
```

Do you have any idea, suggestion, information, whatever?

Can it be some problem with firewall configuration (I tried turning it off (even antivirus) on client side, but this wasn't helpful)?

**EDIT:** I found this Exception in wcf trace log: **The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.**
What does it mean? http://txt.do/xqu7

On the client side is this at log:
**An internal WebSocket error occurred. Please see the innerException, if present, for more details.**

... inner exception: **An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host** http://txt.do/xqf6

**EDIT2:**
I changed binding to net tcp and magically it works. So I think, it is something wrong with websocket binding. Any idea?

Comment: Any response? Have you tried turning on [SO: WCF Trace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271517/how-to-turn-on-wcf-tracing) on client and server?

Comment: Here is server trace log with first warning: http://txt.do/xqu7 ... client side has no response. I'll try test this later once again...