# View contents of outgoing WCF requests in c#

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I have a WCF webservice which calls another external webservice.
My bindings etc. are all correctly constructed and the certificates etc. are being correctly read from the store.
The remote party claims that the request does not have an associated certificate.

Is there any easy way to capture the contents of the outgoing web service request?

I need to be able to verify/prove that what I am sending actually does contain the correct certificate information.

All ofg the information I have found online requires a phd level degree in english to undrstand, not even mentioning the tech speak. All I want is to be able to have a look at the outgoing complete WCF message. Surely that cannot be too much to ask?

Please can someone help me?

Comment: the IIS logs should contain part of the information, you should be able to see SSL certificate confirmation on calls to the functions of the service inside the logs. But i don't recall seeing any info on the certificate itself in there other that it's used.

Comment: See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/420538/Simple-Steps-to-Enable-Tracing-in-WCF - or this other SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271517/how-to-turn-on-wcf-tracing

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/) tool for network packet browsing. It is good for low level sniffing.