# c# DataContractJsonSerializer fails when run from windows service but succeeds when run from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, json, service

I'm trying to write a service as an exercise that will get weather data. I've got it working when run from the console, but when I start the service it fails with the following error

```
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
Stack:
   at         System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, Boolean,     System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(System.IO.Stream)
   at LyncWeather.WeatherGetter.ConvertStreamToWeatherData(System.IO.Stream)
   at LyncWeather.WeatherGetter.GetWeatherByCityId(Int32)
   at LyncWeather.Service1.UpdateLync(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallbackInContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueue.AppDomainTimerCallback()
```

Below are my data contract classes.

```
namespace LyncWeather
{
    [DataContract (Name = "coord")]
    public class Coord
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "lon")]
        public double Lon { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "lat")]
        public double Lat { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract(Name = "Weather")]
    public class Weather
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "main")]
        public string Main { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "icon")]
        public string Icon { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract (Name = "Main")]
    public class Main
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "temp")]
        public double Temp { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "pressure")]
        public int Pressure { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "humidity")]
        public int Humidity { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "temp_min")]
        public double TempMin { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "temp_max")]
        public double TempMax { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract(Name = "Wind")]
    public class Wind
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "speed")]
        public double Speed { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "deg")]
        public double Deg { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract (Name = "Clouds")]
    public class Clouds
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "all")]
        public int All { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract(Name = "Sys")]
    public class Sys
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "type")]
        public int Type { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "message")]
        public double Message { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "country")]
        public string Country { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "sunrise")]
        public int Sunrise { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "sunset")]
        public int Sunset { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract (Name = "WeatherData")]
    public class WeatherDataClass
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "coord")]
        public Coord CoordData { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "weather")]
        public List<Weather> WeatherData { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "main")]
        public Main MainData { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "wind")]
        public Wind WindData { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "clouds")]
        public Clouds CloudsData { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "dt")]
        public int Dt { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "sys")]
        public Sys SysData { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is where I call the DataContractSerializer

```
public WeatherDataClass ConvertStreamToWeatherData(Stream Json)
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer js = new     DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(WeatherDataClass));
    return (WeatherDataClass)js.ReadObject(Json);
}
```

Does anyone know why this might be working in VS but not from a service? Barring that is there a way that I can get a more explicit error to find which datamember it's failing at?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: _"working in VS but not from a service"_ - different data. Anyway, [enable WCF Tracing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271517/how-to-turn-on-wcf-tracing).

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks! I'm having some trouble getting it to capture that information but it definitely seems like a good place to start.

Comment: @CodeCaster Great call. The trace let me see that it's encountering an unexpected character somewhere. I still don't know why it's occurring only with the service but this is progress!

Comment: I have discovered that my firewall is preventing the service from accessing the internet going out and it's returning with different text, which is why it couldn't serialize it.