# How to enable Trace Logging in a VB web project

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer, event-log, tracelistener

I'm currently developing a web project in VB.net.
I have run into some errors experienced more in IE11 than any other browser. I have researched all options related to turning the project cookieless, changed my variables and such around, and tried to make the project as sound as possible for all browsers, but to no avail.

My next step is to enable Trace Logging for the site so that I may ascertain the identity of the error.

The error I am getting is thus:
[image]
As I've siad, I've looked into the dropdownlist that is described in the error. I've changed it. Done everything I could

Thing is, I use the same page (in a sense) on another webpage, and the error does not occur. Similiary, in Chrome, Firefox even IE9 there is no error. Only in IE11.

As I said, I would like to implement Trace Logging. Now I have in my web.config

```
<system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true">
  <listeners>
    <add name="WebPageTraceListener"
      type="System.Web.WebPageTraceListener, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" initializeData="C:\Diagnostics\trace.svclog"/>
  </listeners>
</trace>
```

I have set the initializeData to the C drive for testing (for me) and because I would like to see if another PC gets the error, hence the log should go to their machine.
My

```
 <customErrors>
```

is set to off.

Yet there is no file! In my web.config, I had

```
<trace enabled="false" requestLimit="10" pageOutput="false" traceMode="SortByTime" localOnly="true" writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true" />
```

But removed everything expect for

> writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true"

But still nothing.

I followed [Walkthrough: Integrating ASP.NET Tracing with System.Diagnostics Tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0ectfxd.aspx), specifically the sections on logging through the web.config. I focused on the section titled

> Routing All Tracing Output to .NET Framework Tracing

but following this, I thought I would get a file or something. But nothing came.

How do I get the trace file? Am I doing something wrong in the web.config? The user has full access to the folder.
Can this even be done?

I had this in a C# WPF application that logged only critical erros

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging  logEntireMessage="true" maxMessagesToLog="300" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
</diagnostics>
```

Can I do the same for a web project?
What more can I do?

Your help is greatly appreciated

**EDIT**
Apologies for not posting *what* I'm trying to do.

On page load, the dropdownlist is populated

```
 ddlMedicalAid.DataSource = objMedicalAids
        ddlMedicalAid.DataValueField = "MedicalAidID"
        ddlMedicalAid.DataTextField = "Name"
        ddlMedicalAid.DataBind()
```

Now when the page is rendered, the values are present, and the selected value in this case would be

> Medical Aid 1

When the user enters text and clicks search, the method calls a service, in which the selected medical aid's value and the text is sent. The text has a required validator on it, so there is no way that a null value is passed there. It is for some reason the dropdownlist

```
 Dim objTransactions As ArrayList
    objTransactions = Managers.Transaction.GetTransactionsByMedicalAid(ddlMedicalAid.SelectedValue, strMember)
```

Comment: serviceModel (i.e. WCF) uses TraceSources not the legacy intrinsic Trace object.

Comment: @MatthewMartin i see. thats why i asked if this could be done in this case (web project)

Comment: Yes, you can enable the tracesources for both the client & server side (assuming 2 websites talking to each other) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271517/how-to-turn-on-wcf-tracing

Comment: @MatthewMartin thanks will look into this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe it or not, I just had to change the current .browser file to accommodate the various browsers. This eliminated the main error, working in Chrome, but not in IE11. I just thought getting a tracer would help. Seems this did it

For more help, [Browser Definition File Schema (browsers Element)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228122(v=vs.100).aspx)