# Error when invoking web service in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, sockets, iis

I have installed a web service in IIS and trying to invoke it through a client program.

Basically, this web service is to call another external web service and return output to the client program. When the web service is debugged (even in the same machine with IIS installed) it works fine. It also works when its deployed in IIS and run while machine is connected to direct internet (through internet dongle).

But when it's deployed to IIS (without connecting to direct internet) and called through a client program, I'm getting the following error :

> Failed withSystem.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote
>   server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt
>   failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
>   period of time, or established connection failed because connected
>   host has failed to respond 172.100.30.2:8080 at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress) at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
>   exception) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters) at
>   WSForLkCom.LankaPanel.SOAPServerUsingNuSOAPinCodeIgniter.add_insurance_onerecord(String
>   record, String username) in C:\wwwroot\WSForLkCom\WSForLkCom\Web
>   References\LankaPanel\Reference.cs:line 80 at
>   WSForLkCom.LankaComWS.pushDataToLkCom(String jsonString) in
>   C:\wwwroot\WSForLkCom\WSForLkCom\LankaComWS.asmx.cs:line 37

The error occurs when the web service is trying to connect to the external web service.

I asked our network guys what the IP 172.100.30.2 (in above error) is and they said it's the old proxy server used to connect to internet.

I can't figure out why it's trying to connect through and old proxy server which doesn't exist. I want to know if this can be a configuration problem in the IIS or something else and if there's some way to fix it. Error happens when it's deployed to IIS and called through client program.

Hope I can get some help on this one.

Thanks.

Comment: Check whether your IIS express is correctly configured.Goto properties and click web and see what's your project url.

Comment: Also try adding tracing and see what error are thrown
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271517/how-to-turn-on-wcf-tracing


https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Have you configured the proxy for the server?