# Wcf service writing PUT/DELETE methods crashes the service

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, wcf

I am creating a web service to interact with a database and it is supposed to perform the CRUD operations. Right now it works fine with the read and post operation the WCF service supposed to have a method that is called from within jQuery whenever the page completes load to retrieve a list of all providers and it works fine, however, when I update the WCF Service with a method like this

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public Object PutSupplier(int id, Supplier oParameter)
{
    // Do work
}
```

OR

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public Object DeleteSupplier(int id)
{
    // Do work
}
```

Something happen and no data comes back when the page loads and the insertion operation failed too and I got a 500 internal error?!. Like if the whole WCF Service got unseen or not functioning.

Here is my other WCF Service methods and the calling jQuery/Ajax

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public List<Supplier> GetSupplier(int id)
{
    // Add your operation implementation here
    return DbContext.DbContextManager.GetSupplier(id.ToNullableInt());
}
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public Supplier PostSupplier(Supplier oParameter)
{
    return DbContext.DbContextManager.PostSupplier(oParameter);
}

<script>
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/WebServices/NameService.svc/GetSupplier',
        data: JSON.stringify({ id : 0 }),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (item) {
            $.each(item, function (i) {
                var _tr = '<tr><td class="readonly-"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + item[i].CompanyName + '" style="display:table-cell; width:100%" readonly/></td><td>' +
                    '<button type="button" id="pencilbutton_' + item[i].SupplierId + '"  class="btn btn-success">' +
                    '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Pencil</span></button>' +
                    '<button type="button" id="removebutton_' + item[i].SupplierId + '"  class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Remove</button></td></tr>';
                $('tbody').append(_tr);
            });
        }
    });
    $('table').on('focus', 'input[type="text"]', function () {
        $(this).removeAttr('readonly');
    });
    $(':button[class*="btn-primary"]').click(function () {
        if (Page_ClientValidate("MyValidationGroup")) {
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/WebServices/NameService.svc/PostSupplier',
                data: JSON.stringify({ 'SupplierId': 0, 'CompanyName': $(':text[class="form-control"]').val() }),
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (item) {
                    var _tr = '<tr><td class="readonly-"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + item.CompanyName + '" style="display:table-cell; width:100%" readonly/></td><td>' +
                             '<button type="button" id="pencilbutton_' + item.SupplierId + '"  class="btn btn-success">' +
                             '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Pencil</span></button>' +
                             '<button type="button" id="removebutton_' + item.SupplierId + '"  class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Remove</button></td></tr>';
                    $('tbody').append(_tr);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I would suggest enabling WCF Tracing (http://stackoverflow.com/q/4271517/696140) as it may give you more information.  As far as PUT and DELETE are concerned, I've run into issues with these HTTP Methods whenever WebDav module was installed on IIS except I'd get a 405.

Comment: It seems that I was setting an option within the web.config file that created this I think it is the <enableWebScript /> because after removing it everything works fine :)