# WCF connection issue in windows xp

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-xp, wcf-security, windows-server-2016

We have WCF service hosted as windows service in System1 [used NETTCP binding]

And we have client in system2 which has windows xp. It is working fine.

Issue: We have upgraded system1 to windows server 2016 and wcf service running as windows service. But from Windows xp, client couldnt even connect to WCF service.
Only in XP machine am facing issue:

"system.servicemodel.channels.servicechannel cannot be used for communication because it is in the faulted state"

Any configuration work in windows XP to support WCF in windows server 2016??

Kindly advise

Comment: No error logs? Then how do you know something isn't working? Did you configure tracing on both the client and the server: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4271597/578411? if so, what do you see there? Is the client authenticating with the server? Is the nettcp binding using any security settings? Are there errors logged in the event log (either application or system) on the server?

Comment: If any exception is thrown, we are logging it in system event logs.  Usually we check for that, but in this scenario i couldnt find any logs there.  Net tcp binding security mode as transport.  netTcpBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
    netTcpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Windows;
    netTcpBinding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;

Comment: As windows XP is rather old and no longer patched it could be that the SSL/TLS channel doesn't want to negotiate a compatible protocol. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/windows/desktop/aa374757(v=vs.85).aspx but this should fail with an proper exception client-side at least. And depending how client and server are supposed to authenticate but I assume Windows XP will not be able to login in  an Win2016 server out of the box but I don't know what might be missing or what group policy to enable.

Comment: In Xp machine, From the client side am getting WCF connection issue : "system.servicemodel.channels.servicechannel cannot be used for communication because it is in the faulted state"

Answer (score 0):

Found this in msdn forum (it´s a bit older):

> We have now found the problem. The application are starting some
>   services that WCF demands, the problem is that these services do not
>   exists on WindowsXP(WAS, NETTCP listener and so on). When the
>   application can´t find or start the service then the application will
>   close. Apparently it is not a requirement to have these services on
>   the client computer as long as it is not running the serivice(in IIS).
>
> So when removing the service check from the client every thing seemse
>   to work fine.

[- source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6f9962be-a357-4489-a63b-0f1f4e4f8a7f/wcf-and-windowsxp?forum=wcf)