# Capture the network traffic of the windows application

Tags: c#, wcf, fiddler

I am working in windows application which consumes WCF services(http) which are hosted in another server.Initial load of this application is too high.
To find out root cause of the issue, I would like to see the network traffic when the windows application is running in my machine and i want to know how much time it is taking to make calls and get data from service.

Is there any tool to capture the network traffic when the windows application is running on the desktop.

thanks

Comment: Tried using fiddler?

Comment: Yes, i have tried, but it could not capture the wcf service. when i check log tab , it was mentioned like this Proxy Configuration Script specified an unreachable proxy:

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*

Answer (score 0):

For WCF, you will want to use use WCF tracing. Here is an SO article that talks about how to enable it: [How to turn on WCF tracing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271517/how-to-turn-on-wcf-tracing)