# HttpWebRequest Capture Response Even If 500 Internal Server Error Details

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, webresponse

When the wrong answer(500) comes from Soap Web Services, i want to see the error details. I can use soap tool, i can do this process using a soap tool and see the error details. But using the WebResponse class in c#, i cannot see the error details.

Do you have any information on this subject?

****Soap UI Tool Response Header Raw****
[image: soap tool response header raw]
[image: soap tool error detail]

****WebResponse Exception****
[image]

Regards.

Comment: Is this for troubleshooting, or do you need to get that information into an error message for the user or log entry? If for troubleshooting you can [enable diagnostic tracing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271517/how-to-turn-on-wcf-tracing)

Comment: I need an error message for the users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have reached the right conclusion. And, I wanted to share thinking that someone might need it.

```
catch (WebException ex)
{
    string exMessage = ex.Message;

    if (ex.Response != null)
    {
        using (var responseReader = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            exMessage = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Err Details:

> [image: err_details]

I wish a healthy New Year for all of us!

Comment: Still didn't get the proper message (getting Unicode characters). request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate");
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;