# System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException

Tags: wcf, exception

I am using WCF client server. The WCF Server ist installed on a terminal server. When I am testing it locally everythings work with a local WCF Server.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Fehler beim Deserialisieren des Textkörpers der Antwortnachricht für Vorgang "MixGas". Es wurde das Endelement "MixGasResult" aus Namespace "http://tempuri.org/" erwartet. Gefunden wurde "Element "b:GasMatrice" aus Namespace "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RadaxPpdsLibrary"".


Unbehandelte Ausnahme: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: Fehler beim Deserialisieren des Textkörpers der Antwortnachricht für Vorgang "MixGas". Es wurde das Endelement "MixGasResult" aus Namespace "http://tempuri.org/" erwartet. Gefunden wurde "Element "b:GasMatrice" aus Namespace "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RadaxPpdsLibrary"". ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Es wurde das Endelement "MixGasResult" aus Namespace "http://tempuri.org/" erwartet. Gefunden wurde "Element "b:GasMatrice" aus Namespace "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RadaxPpdsLibrary"".
   bei System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowXmlException(XmlDictionaryReader reader, String res, String arg1, String arg2, String arg3)
   bei System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowEndElementExpected(XmlDictionaryReader reader, String localName, String ns)
   bei System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.ReadEndElement()
   bei System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.ReadElementContentAsString()
   bei System.Xml.XmlBinaryReader.ReadElementContentAsString()
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.PrimitiveOperationFormatter.DeserializeResponse(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Object[] parameters)
   bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.PrimitiveOperationFormatter.DeserializeReply(Message message, Object[] parameters)
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
```

I do not know what I shall do.
The call ist the following:

```
   public string MixGas(double incomingMassFlow, string incomingGasInp, double sideMassFlow, string sideGasInp,
        out double outgoingMassFlow, out string outgoingGasInp)
    {
        var result = Channel.MixGas(incomingMassFlow, incomingGasInp, sideMassFlow, sideGasInp,
            out outgoingMassFlow, out outgoingGasInp);

        return result;

    }
```

The method Channel.MixGas raises this exception.
I am using other server methods without any exceptions.

This server config file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="All"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener"
               type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
               initializeData= "Traces.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

This is the server configuration in C#:

```
   serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(RadaxPpdsServerLibrary.RadaxPpdsService));

     var binding = new NetTcpBinding()
    {
        OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
        CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
        SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
        ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
        MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1000000,
        MaxBufferSize = 1000000,
        MaxConnections = 100,
        Security =
        {
            Mode = SecurityMode.None,
        }
         // PortSharingEnabled = true
     };

    serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IRadaxPpdsService), binding, "net.tcp://localhost:60000/RadaxPpdsService/RadaxPpdsEndpoint");
```

Comment: Enable wcf tracking to find internal exceptions and view specific error messages. Here is the reference of enable wcf trace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271517/how-to-turn-on-wcf-tracing

Comment: I have added this tracing method now I am confused. I get the erorr in error.svclog The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '10675199.02:48:05.4775807'. But the client does not raise any exception.

Comment: After adding 
 MaxBufferSize = 1000000, 
to client the socket connection abort has gone away. The System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException error is still an there.

Comment: Increase the size of maxItemsInObjectGraph in <serviceBehaviors>.

Comment: It works now I have explicitely maxItemsInObjectGraph  to 2147483647. It works. Thanks.