# .NET WCF WebHttpBinding vs WCF WsHttpBinding

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wcf, rest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [BasicHttpBinding vs wsHttpBinding vs WebHttpBinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650785/basichttpbinding-vs-wshttpbinding-vs-webhttpbinding)

In the process of creating B2B application using WCF where data is sent from one IIS application to another.

The question is; WCF WebHttpBinding service VS WCF WsHttpBinding. What is the difference, what are the cons and pros for both?
thanks