# The caller was not authenticated by the service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-client

I am using WCF and found this error:

> " The caller was not authenticated by the service."

I have used this code in `client.config` file:

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_IReceiverController" closeTimeout="00:00:05"
         openTimeout="00:00:05" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:00:05"
         bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
         maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
         messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" />
          <security mode="None">
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="false" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IEMRProWCFService" />
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://pionbuggs-pc:4567/EMRProWCFService.svc"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IEMRProWCFService"
        contract="EMRProWCFService.IEMRProWCFService" name="WSHttpBinding_IEMRProWCFService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="http://pionbuggs-pc:4567/EMRProWCFService.svc" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

And below is the code in the `service.config` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />

  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFService.EMRProWCFService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFService.IEMRProWCFService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="http://pionbuggs-pc:4567/EMRProWCFService.svc" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebConfiguration" maxBufferSize="65536" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `binding="wsHttpBinding"`, try using just a basic, changing you client endopint to:

```xml
<endpoint address="http://pionbuggs-pc:4567/EMRProWCFService.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IEMRProWCFService"
    contract="EMRProWCFService.IEMRProWCFService" name="WSHttpBinding_IEMRProWCFService">
```

and on your service to:

```xml
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFService.IEMRProWCFService">
```

The error is that you use advanced security that requires you to use authentication, unless there are security constrains that require it.

Here's some info about it:

[BasicHttpBinding vs WsHttpBinding vs WebHttpBinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650785/basichttpbinding-vs-wshttpbinding-vs-webhttpbinding)