# How do I get to explore WCF methods with a browser?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, webhttpbinding

I've got a net.tcp service, which I want to make accessible to other platforms (specifically, PHP). For this, I'm using http binding.

I'm creating a http endpoint with:

```
ServiceHost svh = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));
var httpLocation = "http://" + address + ":4041";
svh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.None), 
                                   httpLocation);

svh.AddServiceEndpoint(
                    ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
                    MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(),
                    httpLocation + "/mex"
                    );

svh.Open();
```

Now, when I'm trying to explore the service via browser by going to `http://localhost:4041`, I'm getting:

```
<Fault xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none">
<Code>
<Value>Sender</Value>
<Subcode>
<Value xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">a:ActionNotSupported</Value>
</Subcode>
</Code>
<Reason>
<Text xml:lang="en-US">
The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver. Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).
</Text>
</Reason>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the URL you're attempting to browse (or an example thereof)?

Comment: How are you hosting your WCF?  Is it via visual studio or IIS?

Answer (score 1):

When browsing, make sure to include the full path to the `.svc` or `.asmx` along with a trailing `?wsdl`.

```
localhost:4041/ServiceVirtualDirectory/Service.svc?wsdl
```

Comment: What would be that path in my case? I've tried accessing `http://localhost:4041/Service.svc?wsdl` without any success. I'm not really sure what Service.svc is and where I should take it from

Comment: It's hard to tell, do you host in IIS?  Usually the first slash is the name of the virtual directory where the second is the name of the WCF project.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried accessing `http://localhost:4041/MyService.svc?wsdl`?

Not sure if your service is REST-ful by design and that's why you used WebHttpBinding. 
If your service is actually REST-ful, its format would be 
`http://localhost:4041/MyService.svc/MyMethod/MyData` and you should see the results on the browser. Based on [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1786951.aspx/1) ASP.NET thread, you would need to attach a `WebHttpBehavior`.

If your serivce isn't REST-ful, you should consider `BasicHttpBinding` (uses regular SOAP messages) or its cousins based on your requirements (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650785/basichttpbinding-vs-wshttpbinding-vs-webhttpbinding) SO thread).

Hope this helps.