# WCF over HTTPS with integrated authentication

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to configure my WCF service to run over HTTPS with integrated security, but no matter what I try, I always get the same error:

```
The authentication schemes configured on the host ('IntegratedWindowsAuthentication') do not allow those configured on the binding 'BasicHttpBinding' ('Anonymous').  Please ensure that the SecurityMode is set to Transport or TransportCredentialOnly
```

My config looks like:

```
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceAuthenticationManager authenticationSchemes="IntegratedWindowsAuthentication"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

<protocolMapping>
    <add scheme="https" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myHttpsBinding" />
</protocolMapping>    

 <basicHttpBinding>
   <binding name="myHttpsBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="InheritedFromHost" />
      </security>
    </binding>
 </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I've tried wsHttpBinding, basicHttpsBinding, etc al, but I always get the same error.

Comment: I can't replicate..  Copied over your behaviors, protocolMapping, and bindings to a new WCF service, enabled Windows Authentication in IIS, and it runs fine for me.

Comment: The following links might help you : 1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648505.aspx  2. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36289/8-steps-to-enable-windows-authentication-on-WCF-Ba

Comment: Check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264969/make-wcf-service-integratedwindowsauthentication