# WCF service with both JSON and sessions?

Tags: c#, ios, json, wcf, session

Is it possible to have a WCF service using JSON as request and respond format to also support sessions?

I need to secure my app, which is currently communicating with a WCF server in JSON format and authenticating per call.

I would like to only authenticate at login, and then handle the rest of the requests in a session, but the moment I try to create such a service, I need to change my binding to either wsHttpBinding or netTCPBinding, and the moment I do that, the server no longer accepts my JSON requests. It does however accepts requests from my test client written in C# by simply using the "Add Service Reference" tool.

Using fiddler, I found that the C# client communicates with my service via massively bloated XML.

Here is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <!-- 
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
        -->
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=b77a5cxxxxxxe089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <!--
          The <authentication> section enables configuration 
          of the security authentication mode used by 
          ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <!--
           The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
           of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
           during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
           it enables developers to configure html error pages 
           to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

           <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
             <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
             <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
           </customErrors>
        -->
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>
  <!-- 
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MobiServiceLibrary.MobiServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <!--<endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MobiServiceLibrary.MobiServiceBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"     automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>-->
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MobiServiceLibrary.MobiServiceBehavior" name="MobiServiceLibrary.MobiService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MobiServiceLibrary.IMobiService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <!--<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"     minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="1">
        </serviceHostingEnvironment>-->
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

My Login "contract":

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public partial interface IMobiService
{
    [OperationContract(IsInitiating=true)]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/Login", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    userData login(string pUserName, string pPassword, string pDeviceType);
}
```

My Login 'Implementation':

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession,AddressFilterMode=AddressFilterMode.Any)]
public partial class MobiService : IMobiService
{
    public userData login(string pUserName, string pPassword, string pDeviceType)
    {
        //Do Login
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to attempt to answer my own question, please feel free to point out if I'm still wrong.

After doing some more googling, I found this: [BasicHttpBinding vs WsHttpBinding vs WebHttpBinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650785/basichttpbinding-vs-wshttpbinding-vs-webhttpbinding?answertab=active#tab-top)

Which explains why I've been having trouble ruuning a Sessionful service in JSON format.
It seems that the binding is the main issue: 
**webHttpBinding** is used for a pure RestFul service, and works well with JSON, there is little to no wrapping of the requests and response between the service and client, and per-call re-authentication is recommended.
**basicHttpBinding** and **wsHttpBinding** are both used to add additional functionality and security to the service (wsHttpBinding is simply newer and has more features).
If I understand correctly, ***both basic-and ws-binding depend on SOAP+XML in order to support the additional features, one of these features being session-support***.

Thus, a basicHttpBinding and wsHttpBinding service, is per definition not RESTful and a webHttpBinding service does not support sessions.

So my options are:

1. Stick with webHttpBinding and authenticate per-call (susceptible to replay attacks, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack)
2. Stick with webHttpBinding and use a DB server side to implement my own version of "sessioning". (Prefably by implementing an asymmetrical encryption such as RSA)
3. Modify client to support SOAP+XML

I'm leaning towards option number 2 at the moment.

I'll still appreciate any comments, advice and/or criticism, anything to help me understand this better.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Do U have your wcf service marked as scriptService?

Is this WCFService hosted on an IIS server or just on a service host. I don't know how service host manages authentication. I know it works on IIS

Call the login service from your app. If it succeeds there will be a session cookie created by IIS and you can get that from the response in you  app. cache that cookie and set it in every subsequent service request that you make from the app

Comment: How do I mark the service as a scriptService? Via WebConfig or Contract Attribute?  

I'm hosting on IIS8, but II7 also did not work. I also run it on my local PC for debugging, directly from Visual Studio.  

When I call the login using fiddler, on the locally run service, I get an error returned : **HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type**.  

On IIS8, doing exactly the same, I get this error: **HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/json' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'**.

Comment: That means your login service is not expecting json. It is looking for soap. So you have to make a soap request to the login service.