# What does ws actually stand for in wsHttpBinding?

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding

As stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650785/basichttpbinding-vs-wshttpbinding-vs-webhttpbinding), in WCF there are several different types of HTTP based bindings:

- BasicHttpBinding
- wsHttpBinding
- WebHttpBinding

But what exactly does "ws" stand for in `wsHttpBinding`?

Comment: I don't experience that question to be a duplicate. In this particular case i'm interested in the abbrevation "ws" for this binding, which doesn't neccessarily have anything to do with the ws-* naming.

Comment: yes, but this article [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36396/Difference-between-BasicHttpBinding-and-WsHttpBind]  is ore detailed

Comment: Eh, from the answer you link to in your answer: _"wsHttpBinding is the full-blown binding, which supports a ton of WS-* features and standards "_. You may not agree with the answers in the proposed duplicate, the question is exactly the same. Consider posting your answer there, instead. Duplication and spreading of content is not appreciated. Also, WS-* stands for way more than just WS-Security.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**"Ws" is an abbreviation for "Web Services".**

The name comes  from [WS-Security (Web Services Security)](http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/WS-Security) which is a specification for solving security and integrity problems with the SOAP protocol.

> WS-Security specifies enhancements to SOAP (Simple Object Access
>   Protocol) messaging aimed at protecting the integrity and
>   confidentiality of a message and authenticating the sender.

This all play well with the fact that `WsHttpBinding` is the binding the use (instead of `BasicHttpBinding`) when operatibility is less important, but security is more important. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2650899/2874896) for great information about the two.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between WsHttpBinding and BasicHttpBinding is that WsHttpBinding supports WS-* specification. WS-* specifications are nothing but standards to extend web service capabilities. You can see this :[http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36396/Difference-between-BasicHttpBinding-and-WsHttpBind]

Comment: So, WS stands for Web Service?

Comment: yes. read the article, it is quite detailed.

Comment: My comment was flippant, sorry. I shouldn't have to read the article and would prefer that the answer was clearer.

Comment: Hi Atmane. On StackOverflow, we prefer that the answer to the question be contained directly in your text, rather than left to an external link that might go stale or dead over time. The link is useful, but answering the core question ("what does WS actually stand for") in your text would be even more so.

Comment: Hi Dan, the next time

Comment: You know you can [edit] your answer, right?

Comment: @CodeCaster yes right . give five minutes