# WCF Memory Increases dramatically

Tags: c#, wcf, file-upload, binding, stream

I am using WCF service. The problem I have is its starts using double memory.

I am using **HTTPS** binding

```
<wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="secureHttpBinding" closeTimeout="04:01:00" openTimeout="04:01:00" receiveTimeout="04:10:00" sendTimeout="04:01:00" allowCookies="false"
                 bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                  messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"  useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/> 
          <security mode="Transport" >
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>

 <endpoint address="https://localhost/test.svc"
                 binding="wsHttpBinding"
                 bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding"
                 contract="IWcfContract"
                 name="SecureBasicHttpBinding_WcfContract">
```

Here is the code I am using to upload

```
using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(logsZipFullPath))
{
  // Call web server
  UploadFileResponse response = _webServiceHelper.UploadFile(fileStream, currentDate, ".zip", string.Empty);
  fileStream.Close();
}
```

Here is my model

```
[MessageContract]
    public class UploadFileRequest : IDisposable
    {
        [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
        public Stream FileByteStream;
        [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
        public string FileDescription;

    }
```

My zip file is of 80MB.

The problem I have is at the start of the service its using **26mb** which is quite fine. At the first call it uses **136MB** after call completes it goes down to **26mb**. which is also fine. after the second call to upload it starts using **346MB** 
which again gets down to **26mb** after service call. My question is why it is using 346MB when the file is of only **80MB**? My GC and disponse has been called correctly. But, is this normal behaviour or I am missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally found a work around for this. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2650899/2630817)

> wsHttpBinding is the full-blown binding, which supports a ton of WS-*
>   features and standards - it has lots more security features, you can
>   use sessionful connections, you can use reliable messaging, you can
>   use transactional control - just a lot more stuff, but wsHttpBinding
>   is also a lot *heavier" and adds a lot of overhead to your messages as
>   they travel across the network

I think this is the main reason why the memory usage is high. Our requirement was to use the HTTPS certificate and we are able to use this with **basicHttpBinding**. SO, I changed my settings like this

```
<basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_WcfContract" closeTimeout="04:01:00" openTimeout="04:01:00" receiveTimeout="04:10:00" sendTimeout="04:01:00" allowCookies="false"
                 bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Streamed" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="Transport"> <-- this is the main change
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
```

Note: I changed security mode **none** to **transport**  to support https.

Now, everything works without the issue.
Two possible things which causes memory issues.

1. **wsHttpBinding** overheads
2. Stream mode is not supported in **wsHttpBinding**