# C# How do I add customer data using SOAP V2 in HTTPS (Magento 1.9.3.3)

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl, magento-1.9

I'm developing a C# winapp to add customer data to Magento server. My server is using Magento 1.9.3.3. I have a problem when I tried to add data to the server, using `https` protocol. The code below works flawlessly if using `http`.

This is my `App.config` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="httpsBinding" allowCookies="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" 
              proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
        <client>    
            <endpoint address="https://192.168.1.72/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="httpsBinding"
                contract="MagentoService.PortType" name="Port" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

and this is code for create customer.

```
    PortTypeClient mservice = new PortTypeClient();
            var mlogin = mservice.login("SoapUser", "ApiKey"); //login
        try
        {        
                int newCustomerCreateID = 0;
                filters myfilter = new filters();

                // Create Customer
                customerCustomerEntityToCreate customerCreate = new customerCustomerEntityToCreate();
                customerCreate.email = "tarasdzxc@gmail.com";
                customerCreate.password = "0000000000";
                customerCreate.firstname = "tarawat";
                customerCreate.lastname = "kingposs";
                customerCreate.middlename = "";
                customerCreate.store_id = 1;
                customerCreate.store_idSpecified = true;
                customerCreate.website_id = 1;
                customerCreate.website_idSpecified = true;
                customerCreate.group_id = 1;
                customerCreate.group_idSpecified = true;
                customerCreate.prefix = "MR";
                customerCreate.dob = "10/01/1995";
                customerCreate.gender = Int32.Parse("1"); //1-Male;2-Female
                customerCreate.genderSpecified = true;

                newCustomerCreateID = 
                mservice.customerCustomerCreate(mlogin, customerCreate);
                MessageBox.Show(newCustomerCreateID.ToString());
                mservice.endSession(mlogin);                                 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Unable to create account
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
```

after I ran it and it gave me this error:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException: 'SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://192.168.1.72/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1' : failed to load external entity "https://192.168.1.72/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1"'
```

If I change the security mode to `http`, it works flawlessly but I need to use `https`.
I tried copy url https://192.168.1.72/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1 and enter to browser results is show XML [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i33Z5.jpg).

Lastly, I'm using OpenSSL from Apache 2.4 and I already allowed SSL extension from my `php.ini` but in my `localhost` said it unsecure.

**UPDATE**: Still doesn't work. I got this error from Rom Eh's answer

```
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: 'The content type text/xml; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 470 bytes of the response were: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>WSDL</faultcode><faultstring>SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://192.168.1.72/magento2/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1' : failed to load external entity "https://192.168.1.72/magento2/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1"
</faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: basicHttpBinding is not compatible with HTTPS. You should use wsHttpBinding instead : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650785/basichttpbinding-vs-wshttpbinding-vs-webhttpbinding

Comment: Magento tries to read it's own WSDL file, so PHP needs to read HTTPS. Perhaps server `192.168.1.72` uses a self signed certificate which is something that default PHP doesn't allow.

Comment: Yes, my PHP uses self-signed certificate. Is there anyway to make PHP allow it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP is my coworker and we already fixed this issue days ago and I'm posting this for people who curious about this issue.

Firstly, **his `app.config` is absolutely fine**. The `basicHttpBinding` with `Transport` mode can be used with `HTTPS` but **the actual problem is his SSL is a self-signed certificate**. The error report from Visual Studio isn't giving enough info, you must look at the Apache error log (error.log) too. It always throws these error below

```
SoapServer::SoapServer(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:\nerror:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\magento\\lib\\Zend\\Soap\\Server.php on line 814
SoapServer::SoapServer(): Failed to enable crypto in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\magento\\lib\\Zend\\Soap\\Server.php on line 814
SoapServer::SoapServer(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity &quot;https://192.168.1.72/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1&quot; in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\magento\\lib\\Zend\\Soap\\Server.php on line 814
PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://192.168.1.72/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1' : failed to load external entity "https://192.168.1.72/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1"\n in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\magento\\lib\\Zend\\Soap\\Server.php on line 814
```

It showed the problem was OpenSSL failed to verify his certificate. So we changed the test environment that uses legit SSL and everything works without any problem.