# WCF Over SSL Uses Machine Name IIS 7.5

Tags: wcf, ssl, iis-7.5

I am having trouble setting up SSL with my WCF on IIS 7.5.  I have seen this post:

[WCF not using computer name instead of domain name when viewing MyService.svc?wsdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470111/wcf-not-using-my-domain-name-but-rather-my-computer-name-when-viewing-myservice)

However, the solution for IIS 7 does not seem to be working for me.  In addition, I have a wildcard ssl, I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

I have tried modifying the applicationHost.config to both:

```
<bindings>
    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="<ip or *>:443:<my.domain.com>" />
</bindings>
```

and

```
<bindings>
    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="<ip or *>:443:<mycname>" />
</bindings>
```

IIS Resets seem to have no impact.

Little help anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to answer my own question.  The correct way to fix this is to adjust the web config on your WCF to include httpsGetEnabled="true".  The relevant portion should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

After making this adjustment, you will need to delete, and re-add your web reference.  I rebuilt the project, but I am not sure if that is necessary.

Comment: Actually, I needed to add more stuff.  See this article.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521117/wcf-over-ssl-404-error/1527277#1527277