# WCF SSL Service giving 404 not found

Tags: wcf, ssl

I keep getting a 404 error for my WCF service over SSL. Without SSL it works fine. I can access the service directly in the browser and set a web reference to it fine. In Fiddler it gives an "There was no channel actively listening at end point" error and here is the web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
<serviceBehaviors>
<behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>  
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>  
</behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>

<endpointBehaviors>
<behavior name="Inventory.Product.ProductDataAspNetAjaxBehavior"> 
<enableWebScript />     
</behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>

</behaviors>

<bindings> 
<webHttpBinding>  
<binding name="secureHttpBinding">  
<security mode="Transport">  
<transport clientCredentialType="None"/>  
</security>  
</binding>  
</webHttpBinding>  
</bindings>  


<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"  />
<services>
<service name="Inventory.Product.ProductData"     
behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">


<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" 
behaviorConfiguration="Inventory.Product.ProductDataAspNetAjaxBehavior"    
contract="Inventory.Product.ProductData" />
<endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding"   
address="mex" />


</service>
</services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer at [WCF over SSL - 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521117/wcf-over-ssl-404-error). I had forgot to set the binding configuration - when I did that, it worked.